# Is it possible to make a .plot of scattered points in pixel format "," with a color in hexadecimal value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a list of scattered points in the shape of pixels, which is the format "," and I would like them to have a specific color formatted in hexadecimal, for instance "#AAAAAA".

When I try to use both features "," for pixel and "#AAAAAA" for hexadecimal color using the .plot function, there is an error saying: "Unrecognized character ,"

So it seems that it is not possible to use both features together... this does not work:

```
plt.plot(xpointslist,ypointslist,"#AAAAAA,")
plt.show()
```

But for instance, if instead of scattered points, I remove "," the pixel format, and then there is a line between every two points, there is no problem. This example below works, but links every scattered point with a line to the next one in the list, and the final picture is totally useless:

```
plt.plot(xpointslist,ypointslist,"#AAAAAA")
plt.show()
```

Right now I am using the following code, which is the typical one and works:

```
plt.plot(xpointslist,ypointslist,"r,")
plt.show()
```

The reason why I want to use hexadecimal colors is because I am plotting different lists of scattered points, and each one has a different color, but the colors for each list must follow a gradient, so the final effect when seeing the graph makes sense. For instance I have five different lists of points and I want to do as follows:

```
plt.plot(xpointslist1,ypointslist1,"#AAAAAA,")
plt.plot(xpointslist2,ypointslist2,"#999999,")
plt.plot(xpointslist3,ypointslist3,"#888888,")
plt.plot(xpointslist4,ypointslist4,"#777777,")
plt.plot(xpointslist5,ypointslist5,"#666666,")
plt.show()
```

right now I can not do that, so I am doing the same without gradient, like this:

```
plt.plot(xpointslist1,ypointslist1,"r,")
plt.plot(xpointslist2,ypointslist2,"b,")
plt.plot(xpointslist3,ypointslist3,"g,")
plt.plot(xpointslist4,ypointslist4,"m,")
plt.plot(xpointslist5,ypointslist5,"y,")
plt.show()
```

> So the question is, is it possible to make a .plot of scattered points in pixel format "," with a color in hexadecimal "#XXXXXX" value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use the `color` keyword.

Using `"r,"` is just shorthand for `color="red", marker=",", linestyle="None"`, so you can expand it out yourself here to:

```
plt.plot(xpointslist,ypointslist,color="#AAAAAA",marker=",",linestyle="None")
```

Alternatively, you can use the shorthand (with no keyword) `","`, and then set the `color` yourself:

```
plt.plot(xpointslist,ypointslist,",",color="#AAAAAA")
```

Furthermore, the `color` keyword can also be abbreviated to `c` (thanks @Henrik):

```
plt.plot(xpointslist,ypointslist,",",c="#AAAAAA")
```

For all the available options, see the documentation for [pyplot.plot()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)

Comment: @tom that was quick, thank you very much! works like a charm. :)

Comment: @tom no prop, just thought it belonged there, and decided to comment instead of posting a new answer, or forcefully editing..